# PHP - Adding echo statement into a link array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to modify a link array in php to add a variable at the end of a link. I thought this was a very easy thing to do, but I keep erroring out when I do it. I'm not sure if I am missing syntax or if it is not possible to do it the way I am doing it.

Here is the array without any modifications and it works fine

```
$links[]=array(
"url"=>'?p=worksheet', // this is one way I tried, I also added ''
'name'=>'Worksheet',   // This is where the name I want displayed goes
'order'=>999999,
);
}
```

The variable I am trying to add is `$cust_id`

This is how I am trying to add it:

```
$links[]=array(
"url"=>'?p=worksheet'<?php echo $cust_id ;?>, // this is one way I tried, I also added ''
'name'=>'Worksheet',   
'order'=>999999,
);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`echo` does output at the moment you call it. You're trying to concatenate two strings. And you also cannot embed PHP code within PHP code. Try

```
'url' => '?p=worksheet' . $cust_id,
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

instead.

Comment: sorry, should've been a `,` at the end, not `;`.

Comment: I thought you meant that so I tried it both ways. It omits the variable altogether when I do that

Comment: Not possible. The only possibility is that `$cust_id` is not properly set. THis would generate `'?p=worksheet42'`, if $cust_id was `42`.

Comment: I thought maybe it was not set, I will try to test it out by just adding something in the page to see if it is set.

Answer (score 1):

Use a concatenation operator: (of your choice):

```
$links = array(
"url"=>'?p=worksheet'.$cust_id, 
'name'=>'Worksheet{$cust_id}',   
'doubleQuotes'= "Make variables render $cust_id",
'finally' => $pre-tailored-variable;
);
```

where the last one would be have to made ahead of time:

```
$pre-tailored-variable = "String of some kind with value:".$value;
```

Comment: The way I am doing it, I think maybe my variable did not set correctly, is that what you mean by your answer?

Comment: The variable, or the array? You don't need the square brackets for defining an associative array --- but if $cust_id is set, then any of the above methods will suffice for adding its value into the array--

Answer (score 0):

You can't inline functions like this in PHP...

```
$links[0]['url'] = '?p=worksheet' . $cust_id;
```

Might be what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

```
$links[]=array(
 "url"=>'?p=worksheet'.$cust_id,
```